# Angular Js stop ajax call on home page load when the router is matching

Tags: angularjs

```
 .when('/index', {
            templateUrl: function ($params) {
                return '/' + $params['language'] + '/template/home';
            },
            controller: 'homepagecontroller'
            }
        })
```

My web application home page url is index, on page load calling the template(index) and loading the content.

My requirement is on page(home page - index[url]) load index page content will  be loaded but as per the router again calling the template call and loading the content, but the same behavior has to happen only on page url change not in page load of home page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this is your problem:
You have a common layout/template for multiple pages and loading each page content using angular / AJAX. You don't want to execute this angular / AJAX loading when customer hits URL first time.

Here is the solution:
Load index / home page content using server side script at very first time and store a flag in JavaScript session storage / cookie.

Add an if condition in your route definition something like this:

```
.when('/index', {
    // Get saved data from sessionStorage
    var pageAlreadyLoaded = sessionStorage.getItem('pageAlreadyLoaded');

    if (pageAlreadyLoaded) {
            templateUrl: function ($params) {
                return '/' + $params['language'] + '/template/home';
            },
            controller: 'homepagecontroller'
    } else {
        // Do Nothing
    }
})
```

You can store a variable in session like this: `sessionStorage.setItem("pageAlreadyLoaded", 1);`

Hope this helps.